# MxGraph - hightlight some cells when dragging source

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mxgraph

I have integrated mxGraph in my React application. Now I want to highlight some cells when dragging a component from the editor's sidebar. This highlighted cells should indicate where this source can be dropped.

There is a function, which should provide me the possibility to get the drop target, which should be automatically highlighted. But this function is not working at all and is also never called.

```
makeDraggable: function(element, graphF, funct, dragElement, dx, dy, autoscroll, scalePreview, highlightDropTargets, getDropTarget)
```

Is there another option - e.g. listen to a "start move" event for this drag source or something similar?

My application is more or less similar to the following example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vny2qo6lry

Answer (score 1):

```
 mxDragSource.prototype.getDropTarget = function (graph, x, y) {
            var cell = graph.getCellAt(x, y);
            return cell;
        };
```

this cell can be used as the target cell in your function "funct" by doing this the cell below your cell will be highlighted hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

For dragging cells which are already on your drawing, you can override isValidDropTarget:

```
mxGraph.prototype.isValidDropTarget = function (target, cells, evt) {
    return target._type == 'phase' && cells.every(c => c._type != 'phase');
};
```

For dragging new cells (dragSource) from a toolbar, you can override getDropTarget:

```
mxDragSource.prototype.getDropTarget = function (graph, x, y) {
    let cell = graph.getCellAt(x, y);
    return cell && cell._type == 'phase' ? cell : null;
};
```

In my examples, I have implemented a custom *_type* property to comply to our business needs, but the baseline is you validate the cell(s).